# pythonic/idiomatic way of declaring linear constraints on or-tools CP-Solver

Tags: python, or-tools

This is how I have been creating linear constraints on CP-Solver (OR-Tools):

```
constraint3 = [ None for n in range(N) ]
for n in range(0,N):
    eq = "T3_n[%d] >= T2_n[%d]"%(n,n)
    constraint3[n] = model.Add(eval(eq))
```

Where `T3_n` and `T2_n` are lists of variables created according to the system inputs.

It works, but I have that strong feeling that it is not how I was supposed to be doing it. :-)

Is there a more idiomatic/better way of doing it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Another example where the expression itself if built in running time:

`for i in range(0,I):
    for n in range(0,N):
        eq = ""
        for m in range(0,N):
            if n!=m:
                eq = eq + "ORD_i_n_m[%d][%d][%d] + "%(i,n,m)
        eq = eq + " OURD_i_n[%d][%d] == LRD_i_n[%d][%d]"%(i,n,i,n)
        constraint12[i][n] = model.Add(eval(eq))`

EDIT2:

The point of using eval is that the expression itself depends on the inputs and some logic. It is known only in execution time. So I create it as a String and eval() it. 
This is (sort of) the case of the second example. In other frameworks/languages it is possible to set the multiplier of each variable in a constraint. For example, for other solver, I could write like this:

    `for n in range(0,N):
        constraint3[n] = solver.Constraint(0,infinity)
        constraint3[n].SetCoefficient(T3_n[n],1)
        constraint3[n].SetCoefficient(T2_n[n],-1)`

(of course this is a simple example, there are cases where a hairy logic is used to define the coefficients)

I did not find a way of doing that in cp-solver.

Edit 3:
Another example to show why I've been using eval...

```
for i in range(0,I):
    for n in range(0,N):
        for m in range(0,N):
            constraint14[i][n][m] = solver.Constraint(-M,infinity)
            constraint14[i][n][m].SetCoefficient(TRD_i_n[i][m],1)
            if customer[n]!=customer[m]:
                constraint14[i][n][m].SetCoefficient(limit[customer[n]],-1)
            constraint14[i][n][m].SetCoefficient(ORD_i_n_m[i][n][m],-M)
```

where limit[] is an array of Variable

In this case, it is not possible to write the constraint equation beforehand using model.Add() because the variable depends on the customer selected on the input data. Am I wrong? Please advice.

Comment: Why are you using eval instead of using the variables directly?

Comment: Because there are cases that I cannot write the expression in compilation time. The expression itself depends on the inputs and some logic. It is known only in execution time. So I create it as a String and eval() it. This is (sort of) the case of the second example. In other frameworks/languages it is possible to set the multiplier of each variable in a constraint. I did not find a way of doing that in cp-solver.

Comment: Are you new to programming or python? It's hard to get your reasoning behind the usage of eval. eval should never be needed. EDIT2 use-case is covered by void's answer: just add the coefficients from some other array (which can be filled at runtime) using the same index from the list-comprehension. `model.Add(runtimeCoeffs[n] * T3_n[n] >= otherRuntimeCoeffs[n] * T2_n[n])`. If, by any chance, you want to implement a solver based on some customized domain-specific language,more expressive than for example linear constraints, you will probably want to implement a real parser instead of using eval

Comment: please refer to Edit 3. I do not know how to use list-comprehension to write an expression with logic that controls which variables will be on the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it is right about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
constraint3 = [
    model.Add(T3_n[n] >= T2_n[n])
    for n in range(N)
]
```

Comment: Please, and how could I use this notation to in the example I've included on the "edit" section of my post? In that case I do not know the expression in compile time, it is build in execution time with some logic (a simple if in that case, but there are others more complex).

Comment: The meaning of "Pythonic" can be most closely described as to "easy to read". It is possible to convert other examples to list comprehensions, but result might be more difficult to comprehend than original code. Be careful with `eval` if the program accepts any untrusted user input. Use `numpy.empty` or `numpy.zeros` for initializing multidimensional arrays. Remember, "simple is better than complex", so just keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.append`:

```
constraint3 = []
for n in range(0,N):
    constraint3.append(model.Add(T3_n[n] >= T2_n[n]))
```

I don't know what the return value of `model.Add` is but I assume it defaults to `None` if that's what your intention was